# How to verify the button having drop down menu using selenium in java

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

There is a button. When you click on this button, a drop down menu having two option appears. How to verify this scenario using selenium in java.

```
<div class="hpDropDownButton">
<button class="button ng-binding">Holidays Operation</button>
<ul>
    <li>
        <a class="ng-binding" ng-click="uploadHolidays()">Upload Holidays</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="ng-binding" ng-click="deleteHolidays()">Delete Holidays</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Start webdriver, find the button, click it, find those two menu, then assert the property isDisplayed()=true.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the button

Now :-

```
        Boolean dropdownPresent = driver.findElement("YOUR LOCATOR OF DROPDOWN").isDisplayed();

        if(dropdownPresent==true)
        {
            System.out.println("Dropdown is appearing");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Dropdown is not appearing");
        }
```

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

You are asking to verify whole scenario. You need to first understand what `Selenium-WebDriver` is. Refer [this](http://www.guru99.com/selenium-tutorial.html) tutorial for more explanation.

However you can follow below code,

```
     WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
     String appUrl = "your url";
     driver.get(appUrl);
     // maximize the browser window
     driver.manage().window().maximize();

     // upto code from your button
     WebElement button_element = driver.findElement(button_locator);
     button_element.click();

     // to verify a drop down menu having two option appears
     boolean flag = isPresent(dropdown_locator);
     if (flag) {
        // code bases on dropdown displayed
    }
     else {
        // code bases on dropdown not displayed
    }
```

To verify if element is present or not use this method

```
public boolean isPresent(String locator) {
    return findElements(locator).size() > 0 ? true : false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all collect all the Drop down values in List, List values = Upload Holidays#Delete Holidays
2. Then click on Dropdown WebElement, by using `DropdownFieldName = driver.findElement(by.xpath(//button[@class='button ng-binding'])).click();`
3. Take the couunt of dropdown values, by `drptotalCount = driver.findElements(by.xpath(//a[@class='button ng-binding']));`
4. Now you have expected DropDown values and count of Dropdown Values.

You can take a reference from below code:

```
checkDropDownValues(String DropdownFieldName, String values){
         driver.findElement(By.xath(DropdownFieldName)).click();
       WebElement drptotalCount = driver.findElements(by.xpath(//a[@class='button ng-binding']));
        int numberOfDropDown = drptotalCount.size();
        List<String> allDropDownValues = Arrays.asList(values.split("#"));
 for (int colCount = 1; colCount <= numberOfDropDown; colCount++) {
       boolean flag = false;
      Actualvalue = driver.findElement(By.xpath(drptotalCount + "[.=" + allDropDownValues.get(colCount)  +"]"])).getText();
 String expectedValues = allDropDownValues.get(colCount);
       if(expectedValues.equalIgnoreCase(Actualvalue))
       {
                flag = true;
       }
 Assert.assertTrue("Column values doesn't match", flag);
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Click the button (which should be straight forward)

   - it seems you have some asynchronous call or a delay
2. Wait for the drop-down 'div.hpDropDownButton' is beeing displayed using WebDriverWait:

   WebElement myDynamicDropDown = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.CssSelector("div.myDynamicDropDown")))
3. continue ..

http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp